# How to read .txt data row-wise into table in R?

Tags: r, row, data-manipulation, data-preprocessing

I have a text file that I wish to convert into a table format in R.

I have tried using read_table but it automatically assumes 1 column. How should I be reading in the data instead since they are listed row-wise?

This is how my text file looks like:

```
Id:   0
Category: Toys

Id:   1
Category: Books
Price: 19.99
Rating: 4.03

Id:  2
Category: Toys Young-Children
Rating: 3

...
```

Comment: Why don't you just transpose the text column after you read it in?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the data with colon (`:`) as separator and reshape it into wide format.

I created a new file called `temp.txt` with the data that you have shared and read it with `read.table`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data <- read.table('temp.txt', sep = ':', strip.white = TRUE)

data %>%
  mutate(row = cumsum(V1 == 'Id')) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = V1, values_from = V2) %>%
  select(-row) %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)

#     Id Category            Price Rating
#  <int> <chr>               <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     0 Toys                 NA    NA   
#2     1 Books                20.0   4.03
#3     2 Toys Young-Children  NA     3
```